# ContourPlot color problems

Tags: plotting, color

I tried to use contourplot to a 2D fucntion with rescaled color, the code is given below

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
Num=1000;
Delta=2*3.1415926/Num;/
(*Three components of the function*)
BX[R_,X_,Y_,Z_]:=Module[{r=R,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,dum=X^2+Y^2+Z^2},r*Sum[z*Cos[k*Delta]*Delta/(dum-2*x*r*Cos[k*Delta]-2*y*r*Sin[k*Delta]+r^2)^(3/2),{k,0,Num}]] 
BY[R_,X_,Y_,Z_]:=Module[{r=R,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,dum=X^2+Y^2+Z^2},r*Sum[z*Sin[n*Delta]*Delta/(dum-2*x*r*Cos[n*Delta]-2*y*r*Sin[n*Delta]+r^2)^(3/2),{n,0,Num}]]
BZ[R_,X_,Y_,Z_]:=Module[{r=R,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,dum=X^2+Y^2+Z^2},r*Sum[(-x*Cos[n*Delta]-y*Sin[n*Delta]+r)*Delta/(dum-2*x*r*Cos[n*Delta]-2*y*r*Sin[n*Delta]+r^2)^(3/2),{n,0,Num}]]
(*The function is given below*)
I1 = 0.1;
I2 = -0.12;
R1 = 1;
R2 = 1.4;
B[X_, Z_] := 
 Module[{x = X, z = Z}, 
   Sqrt[(I1*BX[R1, x, 0, z] + 
    I2*BX[R2, x, 0, z])^2 + (I1*BY[R1, x, 0, z] + 
    I2*BY[R2, x, 0, z])^2 + (I1*BZ[R1, x, 0, z] + 
    I2*BZ[R2, x, 0, z])^2]] // N
(*Plot*)
ShowLegend[
 ContourPlot[B[x, z], {x, -1, 1}, {z, 0.4, 1}, Contours -> 50, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
  Rescale[#, {0, 5}]] &)], {ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1] &, 20, 
  "5", "0"}]
```

However the result does not make any sense, I expected a range of color same as the legend given. the result is given below:

[image]

Looks like 0 everywhere, but, if you check the function value, you will see this is wrong.

any ideas?

Comment: What version of _Mathematica_ are you using? The ``PlotLegends` `` package was deprecated in v9 in favor of the built-in option [`PlotLegends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) which is superior in many ways.

Comment: @rcollyer, v7, I really do not care much about the legend. My concern is the color, how can I get as much color as possible on the plotting? and am I right for the rescale part?

Comment: If you remove the manual rescaling and let `ContourPlot` do it, it _usually_ will give you a lot more variation. I tend to manually scale things only when they have to match across multiple plots.

Comment: @rcollyer, if you input $ColorData["Rainbow"]$, it will output {0,1} plus a color bar, does that mean the color on the color bar mapping with the value between 0 and 1?

Comment: Yes, `ContourPlot` scales from 0 to 1, by default. I'd let `ContourPlot` do its thing and then supply `ShowLegend` with the correct scale.

Comment: @rcollyer, what if I only need the output shows the value less than,say 5, and if the value > 5, it's white, what's more between 0 to 5, it maps to the "Rainbow" colorbar. How can I do that? will dividing the function value to 5 help?

Comment: Dividing by 5 won't help as that is just rescaling the function. In that case, you want to set `PlotRange -> {0,5}` which changes what the z-range that is displayed and used to scale the `ColorFunction`.

Comment: @rcollyer, that helps, thank you. I found ColorData[ "Rainbow"] does not contain color black etc, if I need more kinds of color, how can I add more color?

Comment: Use [`Blend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blend.html) to create your own. I've done some interesting things with it in the [past](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3423518#3423518).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was that you were rescaling numbers that run between 0 and 0.4 (the actual range of output for `B` over this range) as if they ran between 0 and 5.

```
Range[0, 0.4, .1]
Rescale[%, {0, 5}]
(* {0., 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4} *)
(* {0., 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08} *)
```

If you want to manually set your own color function, then you should find the range of values the function takes before rescaling,

```
{min, \max} = {NMinimize[{B[x, z], -1 <= x <= 1 && 0.4 <= z <= 1}, {x, z}],
    NMaximize[{B[x, z], -1 <= x <= 1 && 0.4 <= z <= 1}, {x, z}]}[[All, 1]]
(* {7.17192*10^-11, 0.380612} *)
```

Then just plot like

```
ContourPlot[B[x, z], {x, -1, 1}, {z, 0.4, 1}, Contours -> 50, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {min, max}]] &), 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

But as others have said, you get the same plot if you just let the system choose the color function,

```
ContourPlot[B[x, z], {x, -1, 1}, {z, 0.4, 1}, Contours -> 50, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> All]
```